# Help proving that these functions don't converge in $L_1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

so consider this

$f_n(x)= \sin(nx)$

$f=0$

$f_n$ and $f$ $\in$  $L^{1}(X)$

$X=[0,2\pi]$

Now it's true that

$ \int_E f_n$ $\rightarrow$ $\int_E f$, when $E$ contained in $X$ makes the integral of the function exist. Now why isnt it true that $\left\lVert f_n-f\right\rVert_1$ in the $L^{1}$ norm  goes to zero??

Comment: Show $\int_0^{2\pi} f_n^2=\pi$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, calculate $||f_n-f||_1=\int_0^{2\pi} |f_n(x)| \ dx$. Does this go to zero as $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Thats the thing , i must be doing something wrong because to me it does /;.

Comment: Note the absolute value sign...

Comment: yeah i did isnt that the same double integrating sin(nx) from $0$ to $\pi$? im probably missing something trivial but i cant see what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "double integrating"?

Comment: its two times the integral of the funciton sin(nx) from $0$ to $\pi$

Comment: No, that only works if $n=1$. See a [graph of $\sin(nx)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yjckdfga83). If $n>1$, then $\sin(nx)$ takes positive and negative values over $[0,\pi]$. You can still relate $\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(nx)| \ dx$ to $\int_a^b \sin(nx) \ dx$ for a particular choice of $[a,b]$, but it won't be $[0,\pi]$ (it will depend on $n$).

Comment: Oh yeah ur absolutely right , oh my god , thank you . I feel like a retard , Thanks!!!!